# Overwrite a (.pyc) File with Another (.pyc) File?

Tags: java, file-copying, pyc

What I'm trying to do here is replace the content of a python compiled bytecode file (.pyc) with another. However, the method I'm using is not working for some reason:

```
private void copyFile(File fileToCopy){
    File fileToBeOverwritten= FileUtils.getFile(pathToFile, "fileToBeOverwritten.pyc");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fooStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToBeOverwritten, false);
        byte[] myBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(fileToCopy);
        fooStream.write(myBytes);
        fooStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Maybe the `readFileToByteArray(File file)` is not the right one for this scenario?

Comment: What does "not working" mean - do you get an error?

Comment: I'm using it with install4j which is a Java installer builder, so it's really hard to debug. I'm not getting any error, but at the end when I check the magic number of the file that should be overwritten, it's still the same, so the method is not working.

Comment: pls, specifically tell us what is the error you're getting, it'll be much easier to answer, if u can just do that...

Comment: So you're running code through a 3rd party product, and presumably have no way of knowing how it works internally. Did you contact their support first? One common reason why you wouldn't be able to overwrite a file is because the file is open in another application with a sharing mode that prevents writing (happens especially on Windows)

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you, Joni :)